# PHP form data not being POSTED

Tags: php

I created a form which asks for username and password for registration purposes and I sent the data to same page using `action=""` and checking for `$_POST` variables, but data is not being passed through this method. When I print `$POST` array by changing condition to true and reloading the page , the `POST` array is empty and also I can see the variables passed as `POST` in URL.Can somebody explain whats the problem?

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['user']))
        {
           echo "Data coming";
           die();


        }


 else {

      ?>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multiform/form-data" action="">
        <b> Username: </b><input type='text' name='user'> <br> <br><br>
        <b> Password:</b> <input type='password' name='pass'><br> <br>
        <input type='submit' value="Submit">


    </form>

 <?php  

 }   
 ?>
</html>
```

Comment: `multiform/form-data`? There's no such value for `enctype`

Comment: Apart from the fact that `multiform/form-data` is not a correct MIME type (the correct one is `multipart/form-data`), if you don't have `<INPUT>` elements of `FILE` type you don't need to change the value of `enctype`. The default one (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) is the best one in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the name to submit button also.

```
<input type='submit' name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

You are checking the index **'Submit'** in `$_POST` and the submitted form is take the value with the name of input type. So you have to given the name to submit button also like above.

Comment: I also checked for $_POST['user'] but that produced same result initially. But now its working thanks a lot. Can you also help me as to why I can see POST data in the url?

Comment: @user3930213 remove the `enctype="multiform/form-data"` from form tag that is unnecessary. and post data never come in url.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking in your if isset for a post named:
    $_POST['Submit']

Your submit button doesn't have
    name=Submit

As a test to see what you are sending for debug purposes, try putting this in your code, it will help you self-debug:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

"input type='submit' name="Submit" ...
Change to this.
$_POST['Submit']
looks for a resource with the name of Submit when you reload the page, as in your code there is no resource with the name of Submit, the if statement returns false and the control switches back to the else part.
Give a name to the submit button and use the same name in the post varibale option.